# Which hook is used to alter a field's description?

Tags: entities

Which hook should I use to alter description of a field?

I want to add some descriptions to fields in several content types. because number of fields and content types are too many, I prefer to add descriptions programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there's no hook for that. Instead you'll want to use the following API functions in whatever context makes sense in your site:

- [`field_info_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7)

  > Returns an array of instance data for a specific field and bundle.

  Use the function to load up an array of instance data/settings, which you can then alter as necessary before passing back to:
- [`field_instance_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_instance/7)

  > Updates an instance of a field.

  That will persist your changes to the database, and take care of clearing relevant caches.

A complete example might look like

```
$info = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'article');
$info['description'] = t('New description');
field_instance_update($info);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think best place to put the code in is hook_install because it should run only once. Right?

Comment: Yep if that makes sense for your site use hook_install :)